# Ant calling another ant

Tags: ant

I'm having a problem when I try to call another ant build file and copying its result to a directory :

```
<!-- Copying PatientStation -->

<ant dir="../SubProject" antfile="build.xml" />

<copy todir="D:/Export">
    <fileset dir="../SubProject/${fullVersionName}/jar" />
</copy>
```

After the ant call, I'm not positioned in the remote directory instead of the current one.

```
BUILD FAILED
D:\myWorkspace\Build\build1.xml:64: D:\myWorkspace\SubProject\D:\Export does not exist.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont' have a PC in front of me, so I can't say definitely what will work, but normally in Ant, if a directory doesn't begin with a slash, it is assumed to be a sub-directory of the current `${basedir}`.

Try one of the following:

```
<!-- You're in the "D" drive, so don't specify the drive letter -->
<!-- This specifies the current drive you're on -->
<copy todir="/Export"/>
```

Or

```
<!-- If that doesn't work, try this -->
<!-- Windows uses backslash as separators -->
<copy todir="D:\\Export"/>
```

Or

```
<!-- Add a slash in front of the drive letter -->
<copy todir="/D:/Export"/>
```

One of these will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by set your destination folder location in variable.

Try this one:

```
    <property name="tgtpath" location="D:/Export" />
    <copy todir="${tgtpath}">
        <fileset dir="../SubProject/${fullVersionName}/jar" />
    </copy>
```